Wire size for Tesla Wall Connector at maximum output
I’m trying to DIY install the Tesla Wall Connector with 60 Amps circuit breaker.
I’m looking around and see that so many recommendations using 6 AWG is enough, but some said 4 AWG.
So to be safe, I’ll use the 4 AWG but I don’t know what kind of 4 AWG that I can use.
Can someone please take a look at the product page for the wire and give me some advice if that wire work for maximum output?

It usually depends if the wire is in cable or single wires in conduit.  Nothing wrong with using a larger gauge than the minimum listed.  More important is if you have done a load calculation for your panel to see how much extra free power is available.  A 60 amp charger is usually of a want than a need for most people.  Most people are quite happy with 20 or 30 amps.

Base on the manual, for the 32 amps output I can use the 40 amps circuit breaker. So 6 awg wire should be enough to install right? Also, how can I calculate the load for the panel?

Can google load calculation and will find a few online that you can fill out.  Some chargers have load shedding that measures what the house is using and only takes what is available for charging(I only know they are around, not how they work).

Are you running a cable or a conduit?

Looking at my favorite ampacity table, and sticking with copper because the Tesla Wall Charger only works with copper:

60A breaker/48A actual = 4 AWG cable or 6 AWG wire
50A breaker/40A actual = 6 AWG cable or 8 AWG wire
40A breaker/32A actual = 8 AWG cable or wire
30A breaker/24A actual = 10 AWG cable or wire
20A breaker/16A actual = 12 AWG cable or wire

Wire means wire in conduit - two non-white wires plus a bare or green ground (10 AWG, 12 AWG if 20A), no ground needed with metal conduit
Cable means standard non-metallic cable, a.k.a., Romex. That has two wires (black and white) plus bare ground. Mark the white with black or red tape near each end to indicate it is not neutral.
20A is enough for many people and 30A is enough for almost everyone. 40A or more is fine if you have the capacity but really not needed unless you drive a lot or are charging multiple cars.
You need to do a Load Calculation to see how much spare capacity is available in your service. If you have more than 20A available then size accordingly. If you have less than 20A available or if you have more but really want faster charging then there are a number of options available but it is not simply "connect it and hope that you never exceed the service capacity".
